# Is it possible to access the value of a MACRO inside a .bst file?

Tags: bibtex

In a custom .bst file I want to define a string that can be modified from the .bib file. As far as I can tell the way to do this is defining a

```
MACRO {mystring} {"Original"}
```

in the .bst and if necessary redefining it using

```
@string{mystring = "Modified"}
```

in the .bib.

However, in the .bst file I need to access the value of the string. Specifically, I want to write an if statement that checks whether the string was replaced by the .bib file or not. The code I thought would make sense for this was along these lines:

```
mystring "Original" =
{}
{"mystring changed" warning$}
if$
```

However, this leads to the error

```
mystring is an unknown function
```

as it is apparently no possible to push the content of a MACRO on the stack.

Interestingly it works if I define it as

```
FUNCTION {mystring} {"Original"}
```

but in that case it's no longer possible to modify the value from the bib file.

So my question is, is it somehow possible to push the content of a MACRO to the stack, or is there some other mechanism by which I could pass global information from the .bib file to the .bst file that does not belong to any individual entry.

Here's an (non-working) example as minimal as I could make it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@string{mystring = "Modified"}
@Misc{AAA,
  title = "The best title"
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my.bst}
ENTRY
  { 
    title
  }
  {}
  { label }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }


FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

MACRO {mystring}{"Original"}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.title output
  mystring "Original" =
  {}
  {"mystring changed" warning$}
  if$
  fin.entry
}

READ
SORT
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
  \cite{AAA}

  \bibliographystyle{my}
  \bibliography{my}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The macro/string mechanism in BibTeX is there as a 'convenience': the substitution takes place very early, before the fields are passed to the `.bst` code for formatting. So from the point of view of what is programmatically accessible, these substitutions 'don't exist': the value of the fields has already changed.

If you want something flexible, you'll want to have a TeX macro or perhaps a marker value that you can search-and-replace. Alternatively, you might consider the mechanism used by for example `achemso` or `biblatex` to pass data: using a special citation with dedicated data fields.